# How can I modify the GUI of a default Unity window?

Tags: unity, animation, editors, extension

How can I modify the GUI of a default Unity window?

E.g. I am trying to modify the **Animation** window. Here is what I am trying to do for the beginning:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(Animation))]
public class AnimationExtended : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        
    }
}
```

I would expect the code above to hide the content of the **Animation** window completely, but it does not. Why?

Here is what I mean by the **Animation** window.
[image]

[Question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/189996/how-can-i-prevent-the-following-animation-frames-from-affecting-the-state-of-the/190019) which made me want to add a custom feature to the Animation tab.

Comment: The code you've written there is for overriding the appearance of the `AnimationExtended` *component* in the Inspector. It does not refer to the Animation window in any way.

Comment: @DMGregory, it seems it is impossible to modify the native Unity windows as of right now, then. Is it the case? Is it maybe possible to draw them inside a custom window somehow? I mean to draw a native Unity window inside a custom window.